# Proving this mapping is equal to the identity

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Question:

Let $f, g$ be mappings of a set $S$ into itself. Assume that $f^2 = g^2 = I$ and that $f \circ g = g \circ f$.

Prove that $ (f \circ g)^2 = I $. Prove that $ (f \circ g)^3 = I $.

My Answer:

$ (f \circ g)^2 =  (f \circ g) \circ (f \circ g) = f \circ g\circ f\circ g = f^2 \circ g^2 = I \circ I= I $

$ (f \circ g)^3 =  (f \circ g) \circ (f \circ g) \circ (f \circ g) = f \circ g\circ f\circ g \circ f\circ g = f^2 \circ g^2  \circ f \circ g= I \circ I \circ f\circ g= f \circ g \; ...$

I've worked out the first part of the question and reduced the second part of a the question to the case of showing that $ (f \circ g) = I $, but I can't get any further than that. I also noted down that $ f = f^{-1} $ and $ g = g^{-1} $. I'm not sure whether this plays into it. Could someone point me in the right direction or point out if I'm making a mistake. I almost want to say this is a mistake in the book as I know there a couple in this book but I don't want to give up without knowing for sure. If it's of any help, this is from Serge Lang's Basic Mathematics.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second part seems false: take $S=\mathbb{R}^2$, $f(x,y)=(x,-y)$, $g(x,y)=(-x,y)$.

Comment: I think you're right. Seems to check the three requirements and definietly does not hold. Thank you for your help!